# Msbuild to confiture manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber flag as false

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, fastlane

Is there option to configure your build_app script with the following manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber when you're building it using msbuild option?

```
('msbuild', CONST['...'], "/p:Configuration=\"#{CONST['...']}\"", "/p:Platform=\"#{CONST['...']}\"")
```

this is what I exactly run on my Teamcity / Fastlane. I was looking for something similar to

```
build_app(scheme: "your_app_scheme", 
          export_options:{ 
            manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber: false 
          })
```

but obviously this exists in xCode, not in msbuild.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, with the following set of parameters, msbuild won't manage the app version and build number itself. It will set as you declared.

```
/p:SetVersion=True /p:VersionNumber=$VersionNumber /p:BuildNumber=$BuildNumber
```